# Printing in memory object using win32api

Tags: python, windows, winapi, reportlab

Attempting to print a PDF generated with reportlab but `ShellExecute()` is throwing `TypeError: Objects of type 'bytes' can not be converted to Unicode.`

I've tried `pdf.decode('utf-8')` but am getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 10: invalid start byte`

```
from io import BytesIO
import win32api
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter


x = 100
y = 100
buffer = BytesIO()
p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=letter)
p.drawString(x, y, "Hello World")
p.showPage()
p.save()
pdf = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()

win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", pdf, None, ".", 0)
```

Comment: Not much point in passing `"."` as the working directory, may as well pass `None` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are attempting is simply not possible. You can't pass a byte array as the argument to the `print` shell verb. You need to save the byte array to a temporary file, and then pass the name of that temporary file name as the argument to `print`.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to suppress opening of the file in an application before printing? For instance, using a temp file with the example above opens Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Well, not on my machine does it open Acrobat. On my machine it opens a different PDF program. And what about a machine without a PDF program installed? If you want to make this process transparent to the user you should use a PDF library that can print.